# How to get all value displayed from loop in javascripts using d3.js? always got last value displayed in charts

Tags: javascript, html, django, d3.js

I'm using django for my personal projects, and using javascript to display value from database to charts model. But the problem is the value that displayed  is always the last value of iteration

When not using charts, I already checked that the value is displayed in every iteration.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irKmX.png)

When using charts, why charts can't be displayed in every iteration.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnGMt.png)

The code:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
{% block script %}
{% for status in projects_status %}
<h2>{{ status.task }} </h2>
<div class="chart"></div>

<script>

let data=[{{status.user_requirements}},{{status.uat}},{{status.sit}},{{status.uat}},{{status.implementation}}];
let chart = d3.select(".chart");
let bar = chart.selectAll("div");
let barUpdate = bar.data(data);
let barEnter = barUpdate.enter().append("div");
barEnter.style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; });
barEnter.text(function(d) { return d; });
</script>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want each iteration to display charts

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are always changing the same one div. Try appending a new div to your chart-class div:

```
let chart = d3.select(".chart").append(„div“)
```

Comment: still only shows the chart on the last iteration, but thanks for the solution